# Is there a way to call an event handler function to another event handler in Meteor?

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-blaze

I have these event handlers for my template:

```
Template.addPlayerForm.events({
    'submit form': function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var playerName = e.target.playerName.value;
        var playerScore = e.target.playerScore.value;
        if (playerName !== "" && playerScore !== "") {
            Meteor.call('createPlayer',playerName,playerScore);
        e.target.playerName.value = '';
        e.target.playerScore.value = '';
    }
},
    'keypress .addScore': function(e) {
        if (e.which >= 48 && e.which <= 57) {
        return e.charCode;
    }
    else if (e.which === 13 || e.keycode === 13) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var playerName = e.target.playerName.value;
        var playerScore = e.target.playerScore.value;
        if (playerName !== "" && playerScore !== "") {
            Meteor.call('createPlayer',playerName,playerScore);
        e.target.playerName.value = '';
        e.target.playerScore.value = '';
    }
}
})
```

As you can see, the `'submit form'` and the `'keypress .addScore'`both have almost similar functions (i.e adding a new collection to the database). My question is, is there a way that I can make a single function that can be passed to both event handlers? I am new to Meteor and I am just practicing the online tutorial I saw, hoping to modify it as I see fit. Thanks for the help! :D

Comment: I'm not aware of meteor, but in my understanding, Yes. You can do it. Declare a function and instead of writing `function(){...}` just write `'keypress .addScore': functionName`

Answer (score 2):

You can create a function and call it inside the events

```
Template.addPlayerForm.events({
    'submit form': function(e) {
        funcName(e)
    },
    'keypress .addScore': function(e) {
        if (e.which >= 48 && e.which <= 57) {
            return e.charCode;
        }
        else if (e.which === 13 || e.keycode === 13) {
            funcName(e)
        }
    }
})


funcName = function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var playerName = e.target.playerName.value;
    var playerScore = e.target.playerScore.value;
    if (playerName !== "" && playerScore !== "") {
        Meteor.call('createPlayer',playerName,playerScore);
        e.target.playerName.value = '';
        e.target.playerScore.value = '';
    }
}
```

Comment: I thought about doing this but I asked since there might be a different way of doing so when using Meteor. Thanks a lot! :)